# Arguments in Java function

Tags: java, function, class, args

I'm trying to use another class to return data from another class.
This class will either return a password, or a key, depending on the arguments sent to the class.

This is the function in the class that returns the data:

```
public static String main(String args[]){
        if (!args.equals(null)){
            String gen = generatePassword(args[1]);
            return gen;
        }else{
            String gen = generateRandomString();
            return gen;
        }
    }
```

My error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at me.GaryIsASloth.KeyGenerator.main(KeyGenerator.java:34)
```

With 34 referring to:

```
if (!args.equals(null)){
```

The arguments provided will either be "pass", following "true"/"false" which will tell the class whether to include special characters or not. 
Or for the key the args will be null.

I had the class working perfectly when I had it working with the key, and then after modification it worked fine with the password too. However I can't get it to work with both, dependant on the arguments. I've tried null check and length check. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking for null you cannot check `something.equals(null)` as equals is a method and it cannot be called on null. Null is not an object. Secondly, elements in the arrays numbered starting from 0 so the first element will be `arg[0]`.

```
public static String main(String args[]){
        String gen;
        if (args != null){
            gen = generatePassword(args[0]);
        }else{
            gen = generateRandomString();
        }
        return gen;
    }
```

Comment: `return gen != null ? generatePassword(args[0]) : generateRandomString();` is much cleaner imo

Comment: @Idos agree, but for beginners it could be too complicated.

Comment: @idos fix your suggestion

Comment: Maybe it is, but Stack Overflow caters to the general populous and not for the individual.

Comment: The reason why the (args[1]) was was used in the first selection was because it runs with the true/false arg, not the first one.

Comment: @JackEvans, then getting the value is correct, it just looks suspicious as you don't use any other parameters in this method, so I thought it should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
 if (!args.equals(null)){
            String gen = generatePassword(args[1]);
            return gen;
```

just because args is not null, does this mean it has 2 elements?

this here is not so a good idea:

```
String main(String[] args)
```

because java has a method that looks like that
so that coincidence is not allowing you to compile

Comment: This is not the OP's problem..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `if (!args.equals(null))` do it like this `if (args != null)`

Then you should check if you have correct number of arguments, if you want to access `args[1]`

```
if(args.length == 2)
```